# images of magento home page are not seen

Tags: magento2, home-page

> the images on my Magento2 home page are not seen anymore

I enabled cache and disabled also  is it possible that it was?
does anyone help me?
Thank you!!

---

[image]

@ Rakesh Donga  I have attached the file

Comment: what is error facing now ? share me screenshot

Comment: It does not give me any error. The home page can be seen. Only the images do not

Comment: share me screenshot

Comment: Have you tried frontend static deploy?

Comment: shaikh.mushoaib : What's this?I do not know magento well

Comment: @RakeshDonga
  I have attached the file. until recently, the images could be seen

Comment: have you tried running `static-content:deploy` ?

Comment: @RakeshDonga not really a developer, not a magento

Comment: problem in coding so i have tell you run some command using ssh

Comment: @Gaia i think issue is file permission

Comment: @RakeshDonga in ftp the images are there. Permissions: 0644. But because suddenly they are not seen :-(

Comment: change permission 0644->0777 and after check it

Comment: @Gaia try to execute these commands on shell
`php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
`php bin/magento cache:clean`

or assign this task to a developer, who understands magento.